# If $a,b$, and $c$ are reals satisfying $ \frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}=6$, calculate $ x = \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{a^3+b^3+abc}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ \frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}=6$$
$$ x = \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{a^3+b^3+abc}$$

As a trivial solution, I found $$a=b=c$$
then, $x$ will always be $9$.
Despite this, my algebra teacher told me there was another solution that I haven't found yet. Is it possible inside the reals? If so, how?

Comment: If we specify further that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive, then the ratio is always $9$. But if mixed signs are allowed, the ratio can be many things.

Comment: Yeah, the a=b=c condition depends on the validity of the aritmethic mean>=geometric mean inequality, but this doesn´t hold for negative numbers. Besides solving for a, b or c and replacing in the equation for x, is there a way to reduce the expression for x?

Comment: I cannot think of anything obvious. One could probably with some work determine the range of possible values of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

If you put $a=1,b=-2$ and solve for $c$, one root is $c=(17+3\sqrt{33})/2.$ This ends up giving a value for $x$ of about $-101.52$. I think there are lots of ways to make the first equation true, giving various values for $x$.

I gather from Ross Milikan's answer that I misinterpreted the question. I think the OP might mean: *if* the first symmetric equation in $a,b,c$ holds, and *if* the value of $x$ turns out to be $9$, find different choices for $a,b,c$. (I had thought it meant "does the relation on $a,b,c$ imply that $x=9$, which it doesn't, as my (simple) example shows.)

So we have $a=b=c=1$ from the OP and Ross' more general case $a=b=c\ne 0$, in which both relations hold, the symmetric relation on $a,b,c$ and the (unsymmetric) relation $x=9.$ This leaves one to wonder: are there any other triples $(a,b,c)$ [not all equal] making both relations hold? It would seem from comments such triples would have some negative entries.

ADDED: I put $c=1$ in both relations sum=6, $x=9$ (OK by homogeneity), and asked maple to solve simultaneously. One answer was the expected $(1,1,1)$, while the other involved a RootOf(**) expression, maple's way of returning the solutions of a polynomial equation. It was a sixth degree polynomial, and when checking the roots numerically it seems all six roots are complex (nonzero imaginary part). So it looks like only the $a=b=c$ solution works for both equations, sum = 6 and $x=9$, even allowing for negative $a,b,c$.

Comment: I have tested some values here and there in the equation, and i have got some different values. Is there a way to write x in terms of a,b, and c?

Comment: It gets involved. Taking $a,b$ as parameters in the equation giving result $6$ gives a quadratic equation for $c$, whose discriminant must be nonnegative. I think this means $a,b$ need in general to have opposite sign, though I haven't proved that. Anyway, the discriminant is a rather involved fourth degree expression in $a,b$, but one could assume it positive, solve for $c$ with quadratic equation, then plug into $x$ formula, for a real mess!

Comment: From what i have seen here it looks like my algebra teacher might have gotten something wrong. Anyways, in a couple of days I will have the chance to ask him, and then i will post the outcome and close the question. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also have $a=b=c=-2$.  In that case, $x$ is still $9$.  Given the wording of the problem, the value of $x$ should not depend upon what solution you find for $a,b,c$, so you should be able to find one, evaluate $x$ from it, and quit.  If they want yo to prove it independent of $a,b,c$ they should ask.

Added:  $a=b=c$ is a solution for any non-zero $a$, which gives $9$ for $x$  You can probably use the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality) to justify that $a=b=c$

Comment: Yes, i had run into that, since rewriting $$\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}-2+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}-2+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-2=0$$, and since the sums of inverses for positive numbers is >=2 and in this equation all the minimum converges, you get $$a=b=c$$ But all of these breaks apart when any pair of inverses results negative.

Comment: @chubakueno:  good point.